# useQuery hook, client side cache best practices in React Apollo

Tags: caching, react-hooks, apollo

Let’s say we have a component tree in react

```
<Tree>
    <TreeTrunkDetails/>
    <TreeLeavesDetails/>
</Tree>
```

and a useTree hook that wraps a useQuery hook that fetches something like

```
tree {
  specie
  genus
  leaves {
    shape
    size
  }
  trunk {
    bark
    diameter
  }
}
```

We could call useTree in `<Tree>` and then pass trunk and leaves data to

```
<TreeLeavesDetails details={leaves}/>
```

and

```
<TreeTrunkDetails details={trunk}/>
```

respectively.

We could also hook `<Tree>` and `<TreeLeavesDetails/>` and `<TreeTrunkDetails/>` with the same `useTree` hook. Given that results will be cached in the client (assuming we can cache) the performance will be ok

Or we could create a `useTree`, `useTreeTrunk` and a `useTreeLeaves` hooks and the hook each component with its specific hook (and query requesting only the data it needs).

What are the pros and cons of each approach? Is there a recommended pattern from the Apollo team?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the trivial case, it's fine to `useQuery` in each component. In the extreme case, you do add additional overhead per `useQuery` invocation. Each instance sets up a `watch`, which, when the cache updates needs to be evaluated.

If you think you're going to have a lot of `Tree` components on the page, it's best to issue one `useQuery` for each and pass data downwards.